# How can call notifyDataSetChanged from View Holder Class?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I just need to call `setNotifyDataChanged` in `Adapter` from `ViewHolderFirst` class. I added method named setNotify to the `Adapter` it make setNotifyDataChanged but I cant call it from `ViewHolderFirst` class. Hope to solve this problem.

ResAdapter.kt

```
class ResAdapter() : ListAdapter<Result, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun setNotify() {
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return when (viewType) {
            ViewType.ViewHolderFirst.type -> {
                val mView = ItemViewHolderFirstBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
                ViewHolderFirst(mView)
            }
            ViewType.ViewHolderSecond.type -> {
                val mView = ItemViewHolderSecondBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
                ViewHolderSecond(mView)
            }
            else -> {
                val mView = ItemViewHolderThirdBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
                ViewHolderThird(mView)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (holder) {
            is ViewHolderFirst -> holder.bind(getItem(position))
            is ViewHolderSecond -> holder.bind(getItem(position))
            is ViewHolderThird -> holder.bind(getItem(position))
        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return when {
            getItem(position).conditionState == 1 -> {
                ViewType.ViewHolderFirst.type
            }
            else -> ViewType.ViewHolderSecond.type
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private enum class ViewType(val type: Int) {
            ViewHolderFirst(1), ViewHolderSecond(2), ViewHolderThird(3)
        }
    }
}
```

ViewHolderFirst.kt

```
class ViewHolderFirst() : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(
        binding.root
    ) {
        @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
        fun bind(item: Result) {
            binding.apply {
                setStatus(item.selected)
                root.setOnClickListener {
                    item.selected = !item.selected
                    // need call here setNotifyChanged()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Introduce a callback pattern. Notify caller using listener to fragment and from frgamnet notify adapter

Comment: Hmm okey. So, I can't call from it like that. I should use inner class for view holder.

Comment: Making the ViewHolder an inner class is definitely the easiest answer.  And its generally a pattern that makes sense.

Comment: As well as making it an inner class (which is typically how you do it) I'd argue the adapter should be the one deciding if the data set has changed or not. It would be better to give the adapter a ``setSelected(itemPosition)`` function that the ``ViewHolder`` can call (you can pass the position in when binding), and let the adapter handle updating its data set, doing any data persistence, notifying the ``RecyclerView`` that it needs to redisplay things, etc.

Comment: Can you show it in code how do build it?